# How to query "Included items in the Backlog" for BuildRun from API?

Tags: versionone

BuildRuns have 2 sets of backlog item "Completed items in the Backlog" and "Included items in the Backlog". Querying "Completed items in the Backlog" is obvious, but how about "Included items in the Backlog"?

Answer (score 0):

The source for "Completed Items in the Backlog" is `BuildRun.CompletedPrimaryWorkitems`. For "Included Items in the Backlog", the source is `BuildRun.ChangeSets.PrimaryWorkitems` - that is, all of the primary workitems associated with the changesets included in this build run.